# Write Cell Range does not exist in Excel

Tags: rpa, uipath, rda, uipath-robot, uipath-excel

I want to add a formula (Subtotal) in my excel file using UiPath with the Write Cell activity. I have a column going from C1 to C7 and the data start at C2. I want to put the formula to C8 but the Write Cell activity doesn’t accept the range I declare in the formula. You can see it in the screenshot. Do you have a solution?

[image: Write Cell Screenshot]

Best greetings!

Comment: No screenshot here.

Comment: It seems that I'm not allowed to post pictures here yet but I can upload a screenshot on a website (It's in German by the way).

https://ibb.co/KwZYTSq

My idea is to use the click activity and then type into but I don't know if it is the best dynamic/elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is the sheet name right? If it is not you can "Get Workbook Sheets" activity and select the right one.